# Send Logcat output of an App to an EmailAdress

Tags: android, logcat

We are now testing our application with a few friends. Sometimes there are some errors which don't throw an exception. So I don't really know whats the problem was. So I thought it would be a good idea to implement a menu item which allows to send the logcat output to a e-mail address, so that we can examine the log.

Unfortunately I didn't find a hint in the Internet how to extract the logcat from a phone. How to send an email shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>Look at [android-log-collector](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/), as it does what you are trying to do.</strike>

It is not possible to collect arbitrary LogCat data as of Android 4.1. There was never a documented and supported way of doing that, and the undocumented/unsupported way [was locked down in Jelly Bean](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html). For your own crashes, you are better served using a crash logging library, like [ACRA](http://www.acra.ch/).

Comment: hmm thanks. so i have to add the source to my project or to install the app on the phone. right?

Comment: You'd have to ask them, as I have not used their stuff. At minimum, you could look at their source code to see how they read the logs.

Comment: hmm yes i read on the page that developers can use it, but however there is no documentation and i dont know how to start it. but thanksè

Comment: Permission READ_LOGS is not supported for 3rd party applications since API level 16 (4.1). Quoting the developper: "Android apps can read only their own log entries, as a result this app won't work on Android 4.1 and above".

Answer (score 7):

I would also look into Flurry ([flurry.com](http://flurry.com)) which not only gives you general analytics but allows you to log arbitrary info and also logs uncaught exceptions for you.  I set it up in literally 5 minutes, but one thing to keep in mind is that it's not real-time like an email alert.  You'll have to wait a few hours for what you log in your app to show up on their dashboard.  It could also be overkill if you have a really lightweight app, but I've noticed no performance loss in my app as a result of using the service.

Answer (score 6):

I found the [LogCollector](http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/) very usefull indeed (the tip from CommonsWare):

And don't forget to set in your own application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Comment: LogCollector seems to log some garbage, not my app's log. No one line.

Comment: LogCollector seems to be dead.  No activity since 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely recommend to look also at this project [here](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRAHowTo)

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't send an email, but sends it to a server through UDP.

https://github.com/Chemik/logcatudp

The source code is available.  It can be easily embedded in our own app.  I haven't tried to do so.

Comment: Logcat to UDP sources has moved to https://github.com/Chemik/logcatudp . BTW application can send log to email or share it using any other installed app.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file give the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In your first/launcher activity, right after the

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Write below lines: This will write your App's logcat to your device's external storage

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {

        File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppLog" );
        File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory + "/log" );
        File logFile = new File( logDirectory, "logcat" + ".txt" );

        // create app folder
        if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // create log folder
        if ( !logDirectory.exists() ) {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
        if ( logFile.exists()){
            logFile.delete();
        }

        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile);
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if ( isExternalStorageReadable() ) {
        // only readable
    } else {
        // not accessible
    }
```

For sending the logcat to desired email address: use below method

```
public void sendLogcatMail(){

    if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {

        File appDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppLog");
        File logDirectory = new File(appDirectory + "/log");
        File logFile = new File(logDirectory, "logcat" + ".txt");

        if (logFile.exists()) {
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            String to[] = {"yourEmailAddress@gmail.com"};
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(logFile.toURI())));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Log files");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Send some message along");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
        }
    }
}
```

Method for checking whether the permissions for Writing to External storage is given or not:

/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */

```
public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you 2 but by browsing the android-log-collector forum I found a [solution](http://trace.nullwire.com/) that is even easier to handle:

There you can store a php file somewhere on your server (or if you dont want to use your own server, they also have a script on their server). In this php file you can define what shall be done when the post message reaches the server. I just definded a very simple code which forwards the data to my mail adress.

This only works if an uncaught exception was thrown. But one could extend the default uncaught exception handler, so that it's also possible to not only get the stacktrace but also the logcat.

Comment: This link is broken, can you update it or post some source code?

Comment: Yes it is broken, and I can't find a new one. But as you may have seen the answer is almost 2 years old.

Comment: It is an old link. I was researching and trying to do this very thing, and I was just wondering if you knew where it is. No matter, I will try another answer.