# How to send logcat via email?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

Is there any library out there that allows me to receive logs from the app via email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LogCollector's source code is freely available and does just that. http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/

Comment: I've used log collector in one of my applications and it worked well.  I decided to remove it and just let Google take care of the reporting for me though.

Comment: Yeah, the automatic reports are awesome. Especially in Froyo, when you even get call stacks in places where the app hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't think you'd need a library, there's been a massive oversight if you can't just do that with an intent. Though you will need to request access to their email account for that on install.

Edit: http://snipplr.com/view/19973/send-email-from-android-using-intent/

Comment: This, IMO, is not a good option.  Firing an intent would require the user to then see the email and then send it rather than automatically sending the email in the background.

Comment: I was thinking more as a quick solution for personal testing where that wouldn't be a problem. For any release, I definitely agree, and would go with EboMike's suggestion.

Comment: As a user, I would feel uncomfortable about an app quietly sending out an email to somebody, especially when it is log data that could potentially contain information I don't want sent out.

Answer (score 0):

I think we've had this sort of discussion before; take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852181/send-logcat-output-of-an-app-to-an-emailadress)