# Android Email specific TAG from logcat

Tags: android

I have set up a specific TAG for logcat to follow a process. Now I want to email that specific TAG. I am set with emailing thing. I want to know how can I get specific TAG and not the whole logcat.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6173985/1321873

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using CatLog or LogViewer Lite (free on Google Play) is the best, allows you to record and filter (i.e. by tag) the log and send directly via email from the device.

CatLog: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat

LogViewer Lite: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ukzzang.android.app.logviewer

You can of course also use adb and command line to grep and output the log to a file when the device is connected via usb (see [Filter output in logcat by tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173985/filter-output-in-logcat-by-tagname)), but the tools mentioned above are quite handy actually.

**Update:**

If you want it automated without interaction, this lib mentioned in the thread below might be handy:
[How to send logcat via email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586938/how-to-send-logcat-via-email), which refers to http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/

Comment: Thanks a bunch for replying. Those are great tools but I can use them. Is there a way to capture it like STACK TRACE in "crash report"(ACRA) ?

Comment: You mean you want it automated for when the end user uses your app, not during development? Afaik ACRA (I also used it before) doesn't filter by tag, but only reports the actual stack trace. So you would need to customize ACRA and actually attach the log to the send out. ACRA doesn't do logcat/tag filtering. I'm not aware of any lib that does what you want, but I also actually never looked for such.

Comment: You probably don't want an intent, but maybe this lib might be helpful and also has silent mode eventually: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586938/how-to-send-logcat-via-email / http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/