# Debug Android app installation errors?

Tags: android, debugging, google-play

From my application on the Android Market (Google Play), I sometimes get reports from people trying to download it, but it doesn't install. Things like: `"There has been problem installing on my deviceX"`.

I can get very little information from this, and the user probably doesn't get it either. How do I get more relevant information about this, and why is it failing for them (what's a known installation problem)?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the user with the crashing app to install a **android logcat catcher app** and mail you the installation result. For details see [send-logcat-output-of-an-app-to-an-emailadress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852181/send-logcat-output-of-an-app-to-an-emailadress)

Answer (score 0):

There's generally somewhat useful information in the logcat when this happens- you could try getting them to use the logcat application and sending you the log.

Comment: I think almost no users will go through the trouble of this. Do you happen to know some familiar problems on installation?

Comment: The problems I've seen have been weirdness with the phone on some devices (like when there is no space), not with the actual apk. So I can't really help with that sorry.