# Getting log info from a downloaded app

Tags: android, debugging, google-play, logcat

I have an android app uploaded in google marketplace.

I have been reported an error from a user, which happens only in a specific device. 
It is not a crash, the application just doesn't work exactly as expected.  I have tried to reproduce the error using the emulator with the exact android version he's using and it works fine.

I am sure I could determine the problem If I'd have access to the Logcat entries.

I suppose the answer is negative, but it is any way the user can get these entries and send them to me? ( of course I cannot tell him to install eclipse or adb to gather the log entries ).

What is the best practice to be able to get error information from your app, once it is uploaded to the market? ( I don't mean crashes where an error report can be sent by android, just something that it is not working as expected ).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852181

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Since android 4.1, applications can only read its own logs, so I guess my only option is to provide the functionality inside my app, and issue a new version with a functionality to gather logs. However, I think this should be a common use case and there should be a built-in way to do this. (In my case it is failing for android 4.1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application aLogcat can do the trick.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd

And I tested it on my 4.1.1 device.

(I don't know how to post this as a comment instead of answer)

Comment: Thanks. I will not be able to test in 4.1 or above till next week. Just to confirm it works, your phone is not rooted and it works fine?. (It is working in my phone but I have not 4.1)

Comment: Not rooted, and not custom rom. Its Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Beans (4.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

there are several apps on android market that allows to get logs and send them by email or upload them to dropbox... I used this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector

Comment: I was looking at the same one, after reading Robert Harvey comment. But it is not supported for 4.1 and above ("this release removes support for Android 4.1 and above"), because an app can no longer access logs from another app since 4.1. In my case, the problem happens in 4.1.1.

Comment: then there is no options ) you should built it in your app. or find a similar user with rooted phone or with adb installed.