# How can I send the log file of the android device via email from inside my app?

Tags: android

as an error report I want to send the device and/or application log to a email account. For that I prepared a button in my view. Can someone help me with that, how can I retrieve the log files?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of building your own, you can take a look at [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)

Comment: ok, but I want to be able to send the files always. Thats why i want to do it manually

Comment: This has never been supported by Google, and is actively blocked as of Android 4.1. The technique shown in the answer below will, at most, give you your own log file entries on Android 4.1+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send Logcat output of an App to an EmailAdress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852181/send-logcat-output-of-an-app-to-an-emailadress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    log.append(line);
                    log.append(separator);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: What is the variable log in your example? And how can I send this content via an email?

Comment: Its not working, I tried it with the code above and used a StringBuffer for the log variable. The content of this StringBuffer is 0, so nothing has been written into my log. Any idea why?

Comment: Found it, forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> to my manifest

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly improved version, adapted from Ramesh (thanks).  The main difference is to do your own buffering.  It's fast.

```
  private void extractLogToFile()
  {
    // Make file name.
    String fullName = ...;

    // Extract to file.
    File file = new File (fullName);
    InputStreamReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
      // get input stream
      String cmd = "logcat -d -v time";
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
      reader = new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream());

      // write output stream
      writer = new FileWriter (file);
      char[] buffer = new char[10000];
      do 
      {
        int n = reader.read (buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (n == -1)
            break;
        writer.write (buffer, 0, n);
      } while (true);

      reader.close();
      writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      if (writer != null)
          try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
      if (reader != null)
          try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
  }
```